# Script for deleting whitespace for multiple files

Tags: python

I have developed a script which deletes all whitespaces at the end of the file.

```
import sys

with open("/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/XXXXX.txt") as infile:
    lines = infile.read()

while lines.endswith("\n"):
    lines = lines[:-2]

with open("/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/XXXXX.txt", 'w') as outfile:
    for line in lines:
        outfile.write(line)
```

The script works fine but I have two thousand small files in a folder where I need to delete all whitespaces.

Can someone guide me on how to change my script, so I can open each file in a folder and run the script above ?

thanks,

Comment: Not it does not work fine. Your endswith deletes two characters. `\n` is one character. Some systems do not use a "carriage return" `\r`.

Comment: why not `line.strip()`?

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake, but how can I do that for multiple files in a folder ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code :

```
import os
import sys

def removeNewLines(file):
    with open(file , 'r') as infile:
        lines = infile.read()

    while lines.endswith("\n"):
        lines = lines[:-2]

    with open(file, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in lines:
            outfile.write(line)

all_files = os.listdir('FOLDER PATH')

for file in all_files:
   removeNewLines(file)
```